# Visual Studio Go to Definition opening MetaData

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In my Web Site project. From an .aspx.cs file, when attempting to navigate to a definition of a UserControl within the same web site, Visual Studio 2012 is opening the MetaData instead of navigating to the source file.

This was working and stopped all of a sudden.

I've tried:

- Clean & Rebuild
- Deleting the .suo file
- Creating a new solution and re-adding the website project.
- Resetting all preferences in VS
- Reinstalling Visual Studio and reapplying Update 5
- Deleting the ASP.net Temp files
- Deleting temp files under AppData

This was working up until today when it just stopped navigating to the source file. Any suggestions?

Update: Our testing environment is also exhibiting the same problem. This makes me suspect it's a Windows update that caused this. However, I've uninstalled all the updates applied in the last 5 days and the problem persists.

Update: VS appears to be compiling aspx.cs & ascx.cs files into DLLs. This is not the intended behavior.

Update: My other web site projects are doing the same thing so at least it's not a project specific problem.

Comment: Create a separate solution containing a new console or a library project. Do you face the problem there also or it is a problem only with website type of project template?

Comment: @ RBT I didn't actually use a template. I just created a blank solution, added an existing website which contains a dependency on a library project which I also added. I've been working on this project for 7 years. It just started doing this out of the blue.

Comment: did any of the projects in the solution changed .net version? The fact that it is happening in all your projects doesnt mean it is not solution specific, if you share codebase between your solutions.